# rotating a rocket in 2D space and allowing it to move in direction its facing, lua, corona

Tags: rotation, lua, 2d, coronasdk

im new to both Lua and corona and have been trying to get my game to lift off(pun intended)

i essentially want to rotate my rocket both clockwise and anti clock wise and have its x and y adjusted in order to move in the direction its facing when the thrust button is pressed

ive tried numerous ways and am getting caught up in the equations and how to implement them, see my code below(feel free to laugh if its way off the mark)

```
   local rocket = display.newSprite( rocketsheet, rocketsequencedata)
   physics.addBody(rocket, { bounce = 0.5} )
   rocket.x = display.contentWidth/3
   rocket.y = display.contentHeight/1.5
   rocket.rotation = angle
   rocket:setSequence("idle")
   rocket:play()


   local inverseRotation = rocket.rotation  + math.pi
   local speedX = 0.000
   local speedY = 0.005

   speedX =  speedX * math.cos(inverseRotation) + speedY * math.sin(inverseRotation)
   speedY =  -speedX * math.sin(inverseRotation) + speedY * math.cos(inverseRotation)




   function thrust(event)

   rocket:applyLinearImpulse(speedX, speedY, rocket.x, rocket.y)
   rocket:setSequence("afterburn")
   rocket:play()

   end

   function rotateleft(event)

speedX = speedX - 0.0005

rocket.rotation = rocket.rotation - 2

   end


   function rotateright(event)

speedX = speedX + 0.0005
rocket.rotation = rocket.rotation + 2

   end

   controlthrust:addEventListener( "touch", thrust)
   controlleft:addEventListener( "touch", rotateleft)
   controlright:addEventListener( "touch", rotateright)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining speedX and speedY...

This means that the first line of the equation works fine.
The second uses the result of the first line on it, thus breaking completely.

:)